# How to get the width of output cell of Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am creating a custom widget (ipywidget) and I need to get the width of the output cell of Jupyter notebook at runtime. So that I can occupy maximum width with my widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the width of output cell (in px) using `this.el.getBoundingClientRect()`, which returns the following object:

[image]